# how replace a sentence with a special character in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

i have a data frame like :

```
df6= 

ID         Col1

75         Étiquette, étiquette opercule
```

what i try to do is replace the Col1 to have an english information in my dataframe so i tried :

```
)
df6=df6.replace(to_replace=r'Étiquette, étiquette opercule', value='Label, operculum label', regex=True)
```

to get a dataframe like :

```
ID         Col1


75         Label, operculum label
```

But replcae gives me the same dataframe ,i have this issue only with this  sentences .Ithin it 's due to the letter 'é'
Can anyone know how to solve it  ?

Comment: If you use Python 3, replace `'Système ...'` with `'Syst\xe8me ...'` to avoid any possible script reading problem. If it does not solve, provide the full stack trace including the line raising the error in your code.

Comment: it did for the è but not the é and É, should i replace it with  \xe8 too or there is another special caractere ,?

Comment: Your code works for me in Python 3

Comment: i m using python 2

Comment: Works in Python2 as well. What's the pandas version?

Comment: It's the  0.24.2

Comment: It's same for me. But your code works

Comment: my code doesn't work for "Étiquette, étiquette opercule" !

Comment: é is \xe9 and É is \xc9